# Why is my loss increasing in gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

**When the learning rate is 0.01 the loss seems to be decreasing whereas when I increase the learning rate even slightly, the loss increases. Why does this happen? Are the gradients calculated wrong?**

*Neural Network with 2 hidden layers ,128 neurons in the first hidden layers and 64 in the second hidden layer. The output layer consists of a single sigmoid Neuron*

```
class FNN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W1=None
        self.b1=None
        self.W2=None
        self.b2=None
        self.W3=None
        self.b3=None
    def sigmoid(self,x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    def forward_prop(self,x):
        self.Z1=np.dot(self.W1,x)+self.b1
        self.A1=np.tanh(self.Z1)
        self.Z2=np.dot(self.W2,self.A1)+self.b2
        self.A2=np.tanh(self.Z2)
        self.Z3=np.dot(self.W3,self.A2)+self.b3
        self.A3=self.sigmoid(self.Z3)
        return self.A3
    def back_prop(self,x,y):
        self.forward_prop(x)
        m=x.shape[1]
        self.dZ3=self.A3-y
        self.dW3=np.dot(self.dZ3,self.A2.T)/m
        self.db3=np.sum(self.dZ3,axis=1,keepdims=True)/m
        self.dZ2=np.dot(self.W3.T,self.dZ3)*(1-self.A2**2)
        self.dW2=np.dot(self.dZ2,self.A1.T)/m
        self.db2=np.sum(self.dZ2,axis=1,keepdims=True)/m
        self.dZ1=np.dot(self.W2.T,self.dZ2)*(1-self.A1**2)
        self.dW1=np.dot(self.dZ1,x.T)/m
        self.db1=np.sum(self.dZ1,keepdims=True)/m
    def fit(self,x,y,epochs=100,learning_rate=0.01,plot=True,disp_loss=False):
        np.random.seed(4)
        self.W1=np.random.rand(128,x.shape[0])
        self.b1=np.zeros((128,1))
        self.W2=np.random.randn(64,128)
        self.b2=np.zeros((64,1))
        self.W3=np.random.randn(1,64)
        self.b3=np.zeros((1,1))
        m=x.shape[1]
        loss=[]
        for i in range(epochs):
            self.back_prop(x,y)
            self.W1-=learning_rate*self.dW1
            self.b1-=learning_rate*self.db1
            self.W2-=learning_rate*self.dW2
            self.b2-=learning_rate*self.db2
            self.W3-=learning_rate*self.dW3
            self.b3-=learning_rate*self.db3
            logprobs=y*np.log(self.A3)+(1-y)*np.log(1-self.A3)
            cost=-(np.sum(logprobs))/m
            loss.append(cost)
        e=np.arange(1,epochs+1)
        if plot:
            plt.plot(e,loss)
            plt.title('LOSS PLOT')
            plt.xlabel('Epoch')
            plt.ylabel('Loss')
            plt.show()
        if disp_loss:
            print(loss)
    def predict(self,x):
        y=np.where(self.forward_prop(x)>=0.5,1,0)
        return y

F=FNN()
F.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred=F.predict(x_train)
```

Output

Learning Rate:0.01

[image: Learning Rate 0.01]

Learning Rate:1

[image]

Comment: From the plots, it seems that besides an extreme value at the beginning, the loss is quite similar regardless of the learning rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your plots, it doesn't seem to be a problem in your case (see my comment). The reason behind that spike when you increase the learning rate is very likely due to the following.

Gradient descent can be simplified using the image below.

[image]

Your goal is to reach the bottom of the bowl (the optimum) and you use your gradients to know in which direction to go (in this simplistic case, should you go left or right). The gradient tells you in which direction to go, and you can view your learning rate as the "speed" at which you move. If your learning rate is too small, it can slow down the training. If your learning rate is too high, you might go in the right direction, but go too far and end up in a higher position in the bowl than previously. That's called diverging.

Also, good to note that it could be completely normal that your loss doesn't always decrease. This is particularly true if you use mini-batch gradient descent. In that scenario, your gradient may not always be completely accurate, and you might simply make a step in the wrong direction every once in a while.

I hope this explanation helps!

Comment: But is this divergence normal for batch gradient decent?

Comment: For batch gradient descent, it can happen occasionally with larger learning rates. What I recommend is that you try with larger and larger learning rates to see how the divergence behaves. Also, it can also be dependent on the initial state of your network, so feel free to try the same learning rate but with different initial weights to see how this all works

Comment: Thanks,will try.

Comment: Does this also happen with larger initial weights? Because I tried it with 0.01 learning rate and increased the initial value of weights and the loss increased, just as with the larger learning rate, before decreasing.

Comment: That weights shouldn't matter too much. Also, remember that it's best to keep weights to as values roughly between 0 and 1 when you initialize them. Your network will eventually find whatever value works best for the weights. What matters is the gradient (i.e. direction), so regardless of how big your bowl (weights) are, the direction should be roughly the same

Comment: Would using dropout or L2 regularisation also increase loss?I tried it and obtained a loss plot similar to what would be obtained for momentum based gradient descent.